# fitsSystemWindows removes padding

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I have this in my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/primary"
    android:paddingLeft="32dp"
    android:paddingRight="32dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    ...

</RelativeLayout>
```

But there is no `paddingLeft` or `paddingRight` in my app. When I remove `fitsSystemWindows`, the padding comes back. Why? How can I keep `fitsSystemWindows` and the padding?

Comment: This has been addressed in article - [Why would I want to fitsSystemWindows?](https://medium.com/google-developers/why-would-i-want-to-fitssystemwindows-4e26d9ce1eec#.kpokdt33j).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`fitsSyatemWindows` attribute **overrides** the padding applied the layout.

So to apply the padding, you should create one wrapper layout to your `RelativeLayout` and add `fitsSystemWindows` attribute to it, and `padding` to child `RelativeLayout`.

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/primary"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">        //this is container layout

    <RelativeLayout
         android:paddingLeft="32dp"
         android:paddingRight="32dp"
         ..... >                            //now you can add padding to this

          .....

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It isn't that it ignores padding per se, it is that fitsSystemWindows **overrides** the padding with just enough padding to make the view fit system windows.

Comment: @ianhanniballake aw! Thanks for fixing my mistake :) Improving the answer

Answer (score 8):

I'll just add this here in case anyone needs to **remove the top padding when using fitSystemWindows.** This may be the case when using custom action bars, DrawerLayout/NavigationView and/or fragments.

```
public class CustomFrameLayout extends FrameLayout {
    public CustomFrameLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomFrameLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomFrameLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public CustomFrameLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean fitSystemWindows(Rect insets) {
        // this is added so we can "consume" the padding which is added because
        // `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` was added to the XML tag of View.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN
                && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 20) {
            insets.top = 0;
            // remove height of NavBar so that it does add padding at bottom.
            insets.bottom -= heightOfNavigationBar;
        }
        return super.fitSystemWindows(insets);
    }

    @Override
    public WindowInsets onApplyWindowInsets(WindowInsets insets) {
        // executed by API >= 20.
        // removes the empty padding at the bottom which equals that of the height of NavBar.
        setPadding(0, 0, 0, insets.getSystemWindowInsetBottom() - heightOfNavigationBar);
        return insets.consumeSystemWindowInsets();
    }

}
```

We have to extend the Layout class (FrameLayout in my case) and remove the top padding in the `fitSystemWindows()` (for API < 20) or `onApplyWindowInsets()` (for API >= 20).

Comment: and what is the vaule of `heightOfNavigationBar`??